# Facebook connect not returning the session in the expected format

Tags: php, session, facebook

I've been trying to add Facebook Connect to a website, but it didn't seem to get the user id after logging in. So, after a bit of checking around, I discovered what seems to be the problem:

The facebook library expects $_REQUEST['session'] to exist (in the getSession() function), but when I output the $_REQUEST, I get this structure:

```
Array
(
    [url] 
    [base_domain_AppID]
    [AppID]
    [AppID_user] 
    [AppID_ss] 
    [AppID_session_key]
    [AppID_expires] 
)
```

where AppID is the application id.

Any idea why this is happening?

I see that the $_REQUEST['session'] is supposed to have some fields called 'uid', 'access_token' and 'sig'.. the 'uid' is AppID_user, but I have no idea about the other two. I'm thinking that, if there's no other solution, I can convert this data to the object it's expecting, so it can pass the validateSessionObject() function.

I don't know if this is relevant, but this happens regardless of whether I enable cookie support or not.

I downloaded the libraries today, so I don't think I'm using an older version of them.

Edit: in the meantime, I've managed to match most of the fields in my $_REQUEST to the ones expected in the session, except that there's no field called 'access_token'.

Comment: Can you describe how you are doing authorization?

Comment: First, I'm using this with cakephp. So in my default layout I have the login button which, after login, redirects to a method called facebookLogin. There I check if the user is logged in with facebook, and, if it is, also log him in in my application. Only that because of the problem described above, the getUser() method from the facebook library always returns null, so the user never seems to be logged in.

Comment: I have suspicions that you are mixing old API with new API. Old one uses session key, while new one uses access token. Check your FB API init method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems to be the answer. But the API init seems to be fine, and I can't find something that could be from the old API anywhere in the code. In the meantime I've rewritten everything using only the javascript sdk, without using the php libraries, and it seems to be working fine. The integration with cakephp and the php libraries was cleaner, but at least this one works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the problem was that i was generating the facebook authentication url myself as

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$client_id&scope=$scope&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri
```

Instead, when you create the login url using the facebook class, it generates it as a longer version, including 2 important fields : return_session=1,session_version=3

If these fields are not included in the auth url, the redirect does not generate the session value.